# How to import Canvas.js using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

How to import Canvas.js using Jquery?

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any Jquery code that replaces the above html code?

Comment: Code to replace : <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
appendScriptToDocument("https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "jquery-3.2.1.min.js");
appendScriptToDocument("https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js", "jquery.canvasjs.min.js");

function appendScriptToDocument(url, name){
    var scriptLoader = document.createElement('script');
    scriptLoader.src = url;
    scriptLoader.scriptname = name;
    scriptLoader.async = false;
    //scriptLoader.addEventListener("load", scriptFileLoadSuccessCallback, false);// If you want to run any function after load success.
    document.head.insertBefore(scriptLoader, document.head.firstChild);
}
```

Here I am adding an script element to the document with the help of javascript.

Comment: Thank you Sarin-jacob-sunny, but it's not working in my page.

Comment: graph.html:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: scriptFileLoadSuccessCallback is not defined
    at appendScriptToDocument (graph.html:21)
    at graph.html:13

Comment: scriptFileLoadSuccessCallback is a commented line, how that can give you an error?

Idea of scriptFileLoadSuccessCallback is that it will be a function which will get executed after the completion of the task.

Comment: Keep that line commented, then your things will work, I just wanted to give you one idea that successCallbacks also can be integrated. That is not mandatory

Comment: Which line should be commented ?

Comment: See the answer what I wrote and compare it with your code. I have already kept the line commented in my answer.

Comment: can you share what you are trying? I mean your code.